# UserDefaults to store a button selection from an array

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swiftui, userdefaults

Struggling to figure out how to store the selection of a button here and hoping somebody could help. I am first making a db query to return a list of results, each item has a button that when clicked, it will always show that they clicked it. The way it is currently working, while I'm on the page, I can click to add, which works and writes to the db, and when clicked it changes to the Undo button, which also works the way I want it to, but as soon as I leave this view and come back, it reverts back to the original with the "Add" button. If a user presses Add, i would like it to persist and always show the Undo button when the user comes back to this screen. Any help would be amazing as I'm quite new to this.

Code below:

Main View

```
struct AdditemView: View {
    let movie: Movie
    @State var movieitems = [MovieitemsModel]()
    @State var movieID = ""
    @State var selection = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(movieitems.indices, id: \.self) { i in

                HStack {
                    Text(movieitems[i].name)

                    Spacer()

                    if movieitems[i].selected == false {
                        Button(action: {
                            self.selection = movieitems[i].name
                            self.movieitems[i].selected = true
                            self.yesitem()
                        }) {
                            Text("Add")
                        }

                    } else {
                        HStack {
                            Text("Added!")
                            Button(action: {
                                self.selection = movieitems[i].name
                                self.movieitems[i].selected = false
                                self.undoitem()
                            }) {
                                Text("Undo")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Divider()
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            self.movieID = "\(movie.id)"
            fetchitems()
        }
    }
}

func fetchitems() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("movies").document("\(self.movieID)").collection("items").getDocuments { NewQuerySnapshot, error in
        guard let documents = NewQuerySnapshot?.documents else {
            print("No Documents")
            return
        }

        movieitems = documents.map { (NewQueryDocumentSnapshot) -> MovieitemsModel in
            let data = NewQueryDocumentSnapshot.data()

            let name = data["name"] as? String ?? ""
            let yes = data["yes"] as? Int?
            let no = data["no"] as? Int?

            return MovieitemsModel(name: name, yes: yes! ?? 0, no: no! ?? 0)
        }
    }
}

func yesitem() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("movies").document(movieID).collection("items").document("\(self.selection)").updateData([AnyHashable("yes"): FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))])
}

func undoitem() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("movies").document(movieID).collection("items").document("\(self.selection)").updateData([AnyHashable("yes"): FieldValue.increment(Int64(-1))])
}
```

Items Model

```
struct MovieitemsModel: Identifiable {
    var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
    var yes: Int
    var no: Int
    var selected:Bool = false
}
```

Comment: I am not sure UserSettings is what you are looking to use. That is a very limited store. Since you are already using Firestore, why not persist your data there?

Comment: There are no user accounts, and all users can press the Add button (there will be a sum of "adds"). Where would I store this info in the db for each user if there are no accounts? (I hope this question makes sense)

Comment: If there are no user accounts and the selections are incremental, you could save the data back to Firebase by incrementing an integer property on the model (rather than a Boolean). However, you would still need some way of keeping track of the current users choice - User Defaults could be used for that bit (this would avoid a user being able to increase the count anew every time they open the app). For example, you could save a dictionary of movie IDs with the corresponding Boolean selection to User Defaults then check this when the view loads so the appropriate items are marked as selected.

Comment: You need to adjust your model; you need to track the added state somehow so that you know which movies have been added and saved and which movies have been added but not yet saved.

Comment: As @Paulw11 says, the data model should be adapted. Also, is the Firebase store local for just that user, or is it shared by all users?

Comment: @Chris it is shared by all users, so if 1000 people click the "add" button, every user will see "1000" on that item for that movie

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing this is writing another function that saves the movies data back to the database and call it in each button’s action handler.

```
// Example button

Button(action: {
    self.selection = movieitems[i].name
    self.movieitems[i].selected = true
    self.undoitem()
    self.saveItems()
}) {
    Text("Undo")
}

// The save method 
func saveItems():
    // Your Firebase saving code here
```

Comment: I'm unclear as to what would be saved in the saveItems function.

Comment: @SeanForReal It would be the reverse of your `fetchItems()` method, to store the data back into Firebase (most likely as the array of movie data). I’m not familiar with Firebase I’m afraid so I’m unable to write that part.

Comment: Ok I think I understand. The issue is I don't have user accounts, and all users of the app will be able to press the button (with a sum total being displayed) but all users are only allowed to press it once, and I need the app to know if the individual user pressed it or not.

Comment: @SeanForReal See my comment on the question above. User Defaults could be used to store which movies the user has selected. You would then check this and update the loaded data accordingly when the view loads. You will still need to write the data back to a centralised database for all users to keep track of the cumulative count.

Comment: Oh very interesting idea actually. I hadn't thought of that. Its adding quite a bit of complexity having to create new records for the movie and all selections in userdefaults. I guess I was hoping to have it simpler and just store `selected` from the item model in userdefaults, so when it goes through the ForEach loop it would know if `selected` for that particular movieitem[i] is true or false

Comment: @SeanForReal You can store an array or dictionary in User Defaults in a single “go” with one line of code (like [this example](https://cocoacasts.com/ud-3-how-to-store-an-array-in-user-defaults-in-swift)). It doesn’t need to be the whole data model; just a unique ID for each movie with a Boolean to represent whether the user selected it.

Comment: excellent thanks! I'm working on it now and running into some issues, but I think this is a good solution.